# User access to img files

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an issue with images in my asp.net (mvc) project.

In this project I use web service (it is allowed for my IP to work with it). From that webservice I get all the information about details, everything is fine except one thing, I store images of detail as URL in my model, and in a view i just use img tag, img is shown to me, but user, who doesnt have access to this webservice, simply doesnt see this img when he uses url of img it is shown that he cant access this URL...

How could I fix that issue? Downloading all the files on each user request and delete them after seems to be bad solution...

Comment: look the web.config, do you have an "authorization" tag?

Comment: No, but how could if affect that user does not have access to file nested on webservice access to which will have only my server?

Comment: the web.config of the webservice*

Comment: I dont have access to it, this is huge international webservice, so i cant manage it in any way

Comment: If you don't have access,  then you will have to download all the images. If there is some duplicated images, then you can control this by some unique id, to prevent download it again.

Comment: And don't delete it after*

Comment: Yeah, seems to be the only solution. As well I was thinking of possibility with deleting files after users session end, but it is not good too in case of few request at the same time..if one will quit session, files will be deleted, and other users will not be able to access them and will have to make new request to server so as to download files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading files on user request, put them on server and before next request check whether files are already put on server or not, if not download this files related to new request. This seems the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file-info and check that the file permissions are set to "read" for everyone

Comment: What do you mean, I dont have this file on my server at all, I get string with URL of file, and just `redirect` user to this URL, so I have no properties of file in my project

Comment: It seems like the user is being denied access to the URL as he does not have permission to access the web-service. Unfortunately I wont be able to provide a better answer without seeing some code or context.